# Poster with two columns of different width

Tags: columns, width, posters

Why is this so difficult? Tex, stack-exchange, reddit... none have the information I am seeking. My issue is simple, I need to create a poster with two columns: the first one on the left side, thin and with text. The second one spanning the rest of the poster, with images.

Help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using one of the beamer based poster packages, e.g. `beamerposter` columns of different width are actually very easy:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \lipsum
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.75\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth,page=3]{example-image-duck}\hfill
            \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth,page=5]{example-image-duck}

            \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth,page=11]{example-image-duck}\hfill
            \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth,page=34]{example-image-duck}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW! Genius. Thank you that is _EXACTLY_ what I was looking for. THANK YOU!

Comment: @PedroFontanarrosa You're welcome!

Comment: Do you know why my sections and titles are not showing when I implement this package?

Comment: When I use this package, all the \section{} or \title{} information is lost in the rendering. Is it because it is a beamer poster?

Comment: @PedroFontanarrosa To show the title use something like `\begin{frame} \maketitle`. Sections are indeed not supported.